# Not able to individually pose finger because of drivers

Tags: animation, drivers

I would like to utilize finger drivers, example, fist, chop, spread fingers as well as tweak and pose individual fingers. Using a downloaded blend. Something is preventing this.
[image]

Comment: why don't you delete the drivers? if you know the cause....you should write everything in the question which prevents us from asking you!

Comment: I would like to utilize finger drivers, "as well as" tweak and pose individual fingers. Thank you, Chris, for your quick response. If no other option then I will delete drivers. I'm at the bottom of the learning curve in knowledge of Blender. I came here for helpful advice and direction.

Comment: I don’t think you can use drivers and poses as you want it because drivers work „always“ - except you extend the drivers e.g. with a custom variable and do something like „if use_drivers: (…your driver function…) „ and so you could turn on/off your drivers with e.g. one scene variable or you do this on (hand bone) level

Comment: I'd have to look at the rig to see how it is done in this case, but it's always possible to have both drivers and tweaks. Can you share the file? ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))

Comment: Blend file is too large. I deleted all extra clothes except for active one, etc. still 32 MB.

Comment: Maybe google drive? Dropbox? Or try https://wetransfer.com? (there is an option for link, no registration required)